# Does the `$eq` operator work with array dot notation?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to write an aggregation query with `$expr` inside `$lookup`'s `$match` pipeline stage. I found some problems related to the array dot notation.

Imagine a collection `relations` with the array field called `nodes`.

The following query works fine returning correct results:

```
db.relations.find({"nodes.0": { "type" : "User", "id" : UUID("dc20f7c7-bd45-4fc1-9eb4-3604428fa551") }})
```

But the one below returns nothing:

```
db.relations.find({$expr: {$and: [ {$eq: ["$nodes.0", { "type" : "User", "id" : UUID("dc20f7c7-bd45-4fc1-9eb4-3604428fa551") }]}]}})
```

To me they seem to be effectively the same, and I don't understand why the results differ.
I tried to use the `$arrayElemAt` operator, it works, but unfortunately it triggers the COLLSCAN execution plan, which is undesirable, as I have an index on `nodes.0`.

I didn't find anything special about `$eq` operator in the docs, they even explicitly mention that those two expression forms are equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the `$eq` operator work with array dot notation?

No. `$nodes.0` is not a correct expression in `$eq aggregation operator`, when used with array fields.

`$eq aggregation operator` has the following snytax:

```
{ $eq: [ <expression1>, <expression2> ] }
```

You will have to use `$reduce` along with `$arrayElemAt` to access your field in $eq operator:

**Query1**

```
db.relations.find({
  $expr: {
    $eq: [
      {
        $reduce: {
          input: [
            {
              $arrayElemAt: [
                "$nodes",
                0
              ]
            }
          ],
          initialValue: false,
          in: {
            "$and": [
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$$this.type",
                  "User"
                ]
              },
              {
                $eq: [
                  "$$this.id",
                  UUID("dc20f7c7-bd45-4fc1-9eb4-3604428fa551")
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      true
    ]
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/i92dKDs5JJV)

Alternative, using $eq operator `{ <field>: { $eq: <value> } }`

**Query2**

```
db.relations.find({
  "$and": [
    {
      "nodes.0.type": {
        $eq: "User"
      }
    },
    {
      "nodes.0.id": {
        $eq: UUID("dc20f7c7-bd45-4fc1-9eb4-3604428fa551")
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

[MongoDB Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/djJkBveT1d5)

If you want to perform IXSCAN, you can use **Query2**. You have to create the following indexes:

```
db.relations.ensureIndex({"nodes.0.id":1})
db.relations.ensureIndex({"nodes.0.type":1})
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It does work, but unfortunately it results in the  `COLLSCAN` for the `nodes.0` index. As I mentioned in the question post, I need to utilize the index. I guess I will have to change my collection structure and replace `nodes` array with two separate fields.

Comment: @sonderlain I have updated the answer and added indexes to perform IXSCAN. Can you check now?

Comment: thanks for the update. The second approach seems to solve the problem, but I guess I will resort to having `from` and `to` as it has more sense for now.