# $expr query operator does not seem to work with array dot notation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to find documents in a collection matching a comparison between two dates, one of them being in an array in the document.

I found a solution using a combination of `$arrayElemAt` with aggregation pipeline but stand frustrated with the problem.

I originally thought the problem came from how I used the $lte operator with Date fields but I managed to narrow down the issue to a much simpler reproducible one.

```
db.getCollection('test-expr').insert({
    "value1" : 1,
    "value2" : 1,
    "values" : [ 
        1
    ]
})
```

Now trying to find the document with $expr:

```
db.getCollection('test-expr').find({$expr: {$eq: ["$value1", "$value2"]}})
```

=> Returns the document I just inserted.

Trying to compare the first element of the array using dot notation:

```
db.getCollection('test-expr').find({$expr: {$eq: ["$value1", "$values.0"]}})
```

=> Returns nothing.

I think maybe the dot notation doesn't work in $expr but I couldn't find anything pointing that out in the MongoDB documentation.

As mentioned before, I have found solutions to answer my problem but would like to understand why it cannot be achieved this way.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Read about `$in`: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/#in-aggregation

Comment: @DheemanthBhat thanks for your insight. I actually have multiple solutions to this problem but would like to understand why it's not possible to do it this way.

Will edit the question to emphasize this point.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does the \`$eq\` operator work with array dot notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64713634/does-the-eq-operator-work-with-array-dot-notation)

Comment: It's actually the same issue, thanks, but it does not provide an explanation for why dot notation does not work though Mongo docs says otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$expr` allows usage of Aggregation Expression Operators *only*. The dot notation you are using will not work to access the array element for the field `"values" : [ 1 ]`. You need to use the `$arrayElemAt` operator, and it works fine.

Your code `find({$expr: {$eq: ["$value1", "$value2"]}})` worked, because the `$expr` used the aggregation expression operator [$eq](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/index.html), ***not*** the MongoDB Query Language (MQL)'s operator [$eq](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/index.html). Note both the operators look alike, but the usage and syntax is different.

And, the code `find({$expr: {$eq: ["$value1", "$values.0"]}})` did not work - as expected. In the aggregation operator the `$values.0`, the `0` is interpreted as field name, not an index of an array field.

> I think maybe the dot notation doesn't work in $expr but I couldn't
> find anything pointing that out in the MongoDB documentation.

The dot notation works fine in `$expr` also. Here is an example, with sample document:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "val" : { "0" : 99, "a" : 11 } }
```

Now using the `$expr` and dot notation:

```
db.test.find({ $expr: { $eq: [ "$val.0", 99 ]  } } )
db.test.find({ $expr: { $eq: [ "$val.a", 11 ]  } } )
```

Both the queries return the document - the match happens with the filter using the `$expr` and the dot notation. But, this is valid with embedded (or sub) documents only *not* with array fields.

Form the documentation, [Aggregation Pipeline Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) says:

> These expression operators are available to construct
> ***expressions***
> for use in the aggregation pipeline stages.

[expressions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#aggregation-expressions):

> Expressions can include field paths, literals, system variables,
> expression objects, and expression operators. Expressions can be
> nested.
>
> **Field Paths**
>
> Aggregation expressions use field path to access fields in the input
> documents. To specify a field path, prefix the field name or the
> dotted field name ***(if the field is in the embedded document)*** with a
> dollar sign $. For example, "$user" to specify the field path for the
> user field or "$user.name" to specify the field path to "user.name"
> field.

Comment: Thank you prasad for a such a detailed explanation. This is exactly what I did not get.