# $expr not working when finding data in MongoDB matching an array value with a field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have written a query that looks like it should work but I can't figure out why it doesn't.

Firstly - I narrowed down a query to make sure it was actually working. the line with $expr in it proves that the fields are correct ( i.e. the same results show with or without it ) .

```
db.nzpostRecon.find(
    { $and: [
            {"eship.order.packages.0.tracking_number":"AB41045027010225"},
            {"ticketNumber":"AB41045027010225"},
            {$expr: { $eq: ["$this.eship.order.packages.0.tracking_number", "$this.ticketNumber"] }},
            {"eship.order.packages.0.tracking_number" : {$exists: true}}
            ]
```

However, when I remove the first 2 lines, the results don't make sense.  When I run it I get some documents that have a value in the tracking_number field ( in the array ) - but the ticketNumber field is blank - so they are definitely not equal even though both fields exist. I'm baffled by this & think maybe my understanding of that part of the query is wrong.

```
db.nzpostRecon.find(
    { $and: [
            {$expr: { $eq: ["$this.eship.order.packages.0.tracking_number", "$this.ticketNumber"] }},
            {"eship.order.packages.0.tracking_number" : {$exists: true}}
            ]
```

Comment: `$expr` allows aggregation expression operators within the _find_ query.

Comment: @prasad_  as explained in the question - it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: See this post with similar question: [$expr query operator does not seem to work with array dot notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66561527/expr-query-operator-does-not-seem-to-work-with-array-dot-notation/66563295#66563295)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no field named `this` so `"$this.eship.order.packages.0.tracking_number"` and `"$this.ticketNumber"` both evaluate to null or undefined and therefore match for every document, making that `$expr` always true.

The `arrayfield.0.embeddedfield` notation is part of the Mongo Query Language, and is not available in aggregation expressions.

If `eship.order.packages` is an array of objects, `$eship.order.packages.tracking_number` will be an array containing all of the `tracking_number` values from those objects, so you can use `$arrayElemAt`, like:

```
{$expr: { $eq: [{$arrayElemAt:["$eship.order.packages.tracking_number",0]}, "$ticketNumber"] }},
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you!  I have spent hours on this and what you said makes perfect sense - works exactly as expected now.